# Transactions in mysql with InnoDB engine getting saved even with incomplete transaction?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, transactions

I was learning about transactions in RDBMS and i thought I would test it with this piece of code:

`DELIMITER $$
    START TRANSACTION; 
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (0,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (2,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (3,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (4,2);
    INSERT INTO est4 VALUES (4,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (6,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (7,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (8,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (9,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (10,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (11,2);
    INSERT INTO test4 VALUES (12,2);
    END;
    DELIMITER ;`

I intentionally kept the 5th insert statement incorrect so that I could test how transaction works. When I executed the query, MySQL threw an error as expected but all the queries upto the 4th insert were still saved in the table! Why is it happening?
And yes I am using InnoDB engine which supports transaction. I use 14.14 version of MySQL.
Also, I was wondering what is the use of savepoints? Suppose I use savepoints in my transaction so that I could rollback to last successful transaction savepoint in case of a failed after transaction. What happens after the transaction is terminated due to failure? What roll does savepoint play from then on?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You may wand to check autocommit: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html

Comment: Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: I tried to modify my code like this:   START TRANSACTION; SET autocommit=0  and then the insert statements. It did not work! :(